# Kind of live debugging possible? (Especially UI manipulation)

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-runtime

I would like to know if there is a way to manipulate an App's UI live while running?
I am not a designer and I have many problems sometimes regarding matching colours etc.

The next problem is that anytime I would like to change e.g. the colour of a control I have to quit the App then go to VS2012, apply my changes, build and execute it again to see simple changes.
I know that I see any changes in the designer but I have to see the resulting screen to get an impression of the whole.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a secret keypress while Debug flag is set, that raises a form and allows you to select controls and expose a property sheet for them. Be a bit of work to get right, and a good stick of code even using reflection. Might be better off with a storyboard type app to do your designing.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike styles in WPF which can be dynamically adjusted (which made this type of run-time adjustment simple), there isn't as elegant of a solution for Windows Store apps. Ideally, you'd have all of your UI and colors, etc. defined in XAML files and not settable through other means (as it becomes a longer term maintenance issue).

I'd suggest just adding enough test data and configuration so that you can see the look and feel of the pages (with colors, etc.) at design-time. Blend and Visual Studio are now quite good at showing a very reasonable near final rendering of the elements of the application. It's generally not too difficult to do anymore.

One thing I've done in the past was to make a single page/form that contained all of the styles and controls in a large scroll viewer. Then, we set it so it was configurable to the be the first thing to run. The tweak/build cycle was pretty fast, and the results were still very manageable.